# Unknown Runtime When Using c++11 instead if c++14

Tags: c++, string, c++11, runtime-error

I have come across the following error when I am compiling code.  I have tried to look through my code to find the conversion error, but I don't see it.

The error occurs when compiling on compiles and runs on
g++ (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)

When I compile on Ubuntu, I get no errors and it runs.  (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

This is the error.

```
/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-8.3.1-20191121/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1067: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference = char&; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

main.cpp

```
//Here is where I can take a string and generate a pseudo-random password from it 
std::string passGen(std::string user)
{
    char passwordArray[9];
    int achar;
    srand (time(0));    
    for (int x=0; x <= 8; x++)
    {
        achar = (user[x] * (rand()%100))%26 + 97;
        passwordArray[x] = (char)achar;
    }   
    return passwordArray;
}
        
//This reads the filename that is passed in and builds the linked list of names and uses the password generator and generates passwords for each username. 
void readFile(std::string newFile){
    ifstream inFile(newFile);
    std::string firstWord;
    
    while(inFile >> firstWord)
    {
        listOfNames->InsertAtHead(firstWord, passGen(firstWord));
        inFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    inFile.close();
}
```

Comment: “ All of my header and class files.”—No, please reduce this to a [mre] rather than expecting strangers to wade through a few hundred lines of code. Please revisit [ask].

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown syntax"? You appear to have a runtime error.

Comment: Looks like an invalid index for `std::string::operator[]`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where the issue was. It is here:

```
{
    char passwordArray[9];
    int achar;
    srand (time(0));    
    for (int x=0; x <= 8; x++)
    {
        achar = (user[x] * (rand()%100))%26 + 97;
        passwordArray[x] = (char)achar;
    }   
    return passwordArray;
}
```

The error occurred when I would pass a name that is shorter than 9 characters to this method.  If a name was too short, than user[x] would have nothing to access.  I had to alter this to

```
user[x % user.size()]
```

I didn't realize that there was that much of a difference between compilers.  After seeing my error, I am surprised that it ran successfully in Ubuntu.

Comment: Undefined behavior is just that: undefined. It's not just different between compilers, it can be different on the same compiler with different flags, or even with the same flags, but in different runs.